# Regarding Scroll View

Tags: iphone

How to Select the current image in Scroll View and How  to save that image(Original Image from My app) to Photo Album of iphone Please help me

Answer (score 0):

To select an image you might want to use the Views touches to sense a tap or double tap or something of the sort to mark it as selected, to save to iphone photo album all you have to do it use the following method UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void *contextInfo).